# How to properly Tokenize a string

Tags: c++, string, token

I'm looking for a c++ equivalent of `sscanf`.

```
  string a,b,c;
  string line = "data1,data2,data3";
```

How to do I assign `data1` to `"a"`, `data2` to `b`and `data3` to `c`.

Answer (score 3):

If your delimiter is a single character, you can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) with an [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and a custom delimiter.

```
const auto text = std::string {"alpha,beta,gamma"};
const auto delim = ',';
auto token = std::string {};
auto iss = std::istringstream {text};
while (std::getline(iss, token, delim))
  std::cout << "Parsed token: '" << token << "'\n";
```

Or you could use a [regular expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex).

```
const auto text = std::string {"alpha,beta,gamma"};
const auto pattern = std::regex {"[^,]+"};
const auto first = std::sregex_iterator {text.cbegin(), text.cend(), pattern};
const auto last = std::sregex_iterator {};
for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it)
  std::cout << "Parsed token: '" << it->str() << "'\n";
```

Both solutions will probably be much slower than using [`std::sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf).

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you want to split a `string` which contain `,` as the limit. You can use `getline` and `stringstream` to achieve this.

First, you change the `string` into a stream using `stringstream`

```
stringstream ss(line);
```

After that, you can use `getline` to split it using delimiter `,`

```
while(getline(ss,tmp,',')) //Here you use string tmp to save it
```

And finally, you can use`tmp` and push it into a `vector <string>`. Here is the full program example.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string line = "data1,data2,data3";
    stringstream ss(line);
    vector < string > result;string tmp;
    while(getline(ss,tmp,',')){
        result.push_back(tmp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```